# How to get the svg position within document?

Tags: html, d3.js, svg

I have a main SVG and can't find the right way to get its offset taking into account other page elements and scrolling.

For example, using the solution explained in [this page](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm) and doing the following I get `{"x":null,"y":null}`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(getPosition(d3.select('svg').node())));
```

I need a way to get the left and top offsets because when I use `getBoundingClientRect` on mouse movements it returns absolute page coordinates and not zero based within the main SVG so I have no way to tell the left or top offsets to normalize it to zero.

For example, in this case:

```
<body>
  <img width="600" height="600" />
  <svg width="1500" height="650"/>
</body>
```

I would need to get the 600 top offset plus the scrolling which I get from `document.documentElement.scrollTop` but I can't find a way to get the 600 Y offset from any d3js API.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it sounds like you need this to calculate your mouse position relative to the SVG's origin. Are you aware of [`d3.mouse()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#mouse) which will free you from this coordinate hassle? Pass in your SVG node `d3.mouse(d3.select("svg").node())` and you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the solution proposed in the page you linked because SVG does not support [element.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop).

An easy alternative is using the property `top` of [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const offset = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().top;

console.log(offset)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<img width="600" height="600"/>
<svg width="1500" height="650"/>
```

If you still want to use `offsetTop`, wrap the SVG in an HTML container, like a `<div>`:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const offset = svg.node().parentNode.offsetTop;

console.log(offset)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<img width="600" height="600" />
<div>
  <svg width="1500" height="650" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! but the result I see is 8 and not 600 ... according to the `img` height it has above it should be 600.

Comment: The result I see is 612 (there are some margins in the HTML, so the value is not exactly 600).